# Toggle icons in a selected row

Tags: angular, ngfor, selecteditem, selectedindex

**Working stacklitz** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rlkrzv?file=src/app/play-list-page/play-list-page.component.html

Im trying to toggle between play and pause icons of a selected row, but when a song starts playing,
the whole table gets a "pause" icon (examples below).

Highlighting a specific row works fine, toggle between play and pause functions and icons also,

its just toggling the icons in the selected row..

**Paused Song**
[image]

**Playing Song**

[image]

**Component.html**

```html
                    <tr *ngFor="let song of playListSongs?.tracks | search:searchTerm; let i = index;" [class.selected]="i==selectedRow" id="selectttt">
                        <td *ngIf="!isPlaying">
                            <img src="../assets/play_line_icon.png" class="playBtn" (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id,i);
                            getSongInfo(song);setClickedRow(i)" id="imgClickAndChange">
                        </td>
                        <td *ngIf="isPlaying">
                            <img src="../assets/pause_line_icon.png" class="pauseBtn" (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id,i);
                            getSongInfo(song);setClickedRow(i)" id="imgClickAndChange">
                        </td>
                        <!-- <img class="playBtn" src="..\assets\play_line_icon.png"> -->
                        <td><img src="..\assets\not_liked.png" id="likedImg" (click)="toggleLikedSongs(song.track_id);setClickedRow(i)" style="cursor:pointer"></td>
                        <td> {{song.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.artists_names}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.album_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.release_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
 isPlaying:boolean=false

  setClickedRow(index: any) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
 }


togglePlaystateSong(id: number,index:number) {

    // let image = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    let image2 = <HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2"));
     
    if (!this.selectedSong || this.selectedSong.track_id !== id) {
      const token = this.playListsAPI.generateToken();
      const songUrl = `http://api.sprintt.co/spotify/play/${id}?access=${token}`;
      this.player.src = songUrl;
      this.player.load();
      this.player.play();
      console.log("row's index:", index);
this.isPlaying=true;
      // (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("bars")).value="0";
      // this.player.currentTime=0;
      
      // image.src = "../assets/pause_line_icon.png";
      image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_pause.png";
    } else {
      if (this.player.paused) {
        this.isPlaying=true;
        this.player.play();
        // image.src = "../assets/pause_line_icon.png";
        image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_pause.png";

      } else {
        this.player.pause();
        this.isPlaying=false;
        // image.src = "../assets/play_line_icon.png";
        image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_play.png";
      }
    }
  }
```

**Component.css**

```css
.selected {
    background: rgba(29, 185, 84, 0.2) !important;
    /* color: white; */
}
.playBtn {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* content: url("/assets/play_line_icon.png"); */
}
.tableWrapper table tr:hover .playBtn {
  visibility: visible;
  padding-top: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected .pauseBtn {
    content: url("/assets/pause_line_icon.png");
    visibility: visible;
    width: 19.98px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.selected .playBtn {
    content: url("/assets/play_line_icon.png");
    visibility: visible;
    width: 19.98px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are showing the pause picture for every song, you need to make sure you are only showing it for the selected item, make the following change in your template:

```
<td *ngIf="isPlaying">
   <img
       src="../assets/pause_line_icon.png"
       class="pauseBtn"
       (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id,i);getSongInfo(song);setClickedRow(i)"
       id="imgClickAndChange"
       *ngIf="selectedRow === i"
   />
</td>
```

the change is adding `*ngIf="selectedRow === i"` on the img

see [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rlkrzv-8hztyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fplay-list-page%2Fplay-list-page.component.html)

Comment: Thanks!
In addition to that, after clicking on play icon, the rest of the play icons in the list disappear, probably because of the other *ngIf before that..
Could you help me with that also? :)

Comment: yes, I've updated the stackblitz, changed the `ngIf` for both the play and pause `td`s